# How to split URL parameters in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rawurldecode() {

  # This is perhaps a risky gambit, but since all escape characters must be
  # encoded, we can replace %NN with \xNN and pass the lot to printf -b, which
  # will decode hex for us

  printf -v REPLY '%b' "${1//%/\\x}" # You can either set a return variable (FASTER)

  echo "${REPLY}"  #+or echo the result (EASIER)... or both... :p
}

echo -e "Content-type: video/x-matroska\n"

arr=(${QUERY_STRING//=/ })
ffmpeg -i "$(rawurldecode ${arr[1]})" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -f matroska - 2>/dev/null &
pid=$!
trap "kill $pid" SIGTERM SIGPIPE
wait
```

I want to change it so it can handle multiple parameters in the query string like this:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

currently the arr regex split is based on `=` so it can only handle one parameter. I am not sure how to change this regex so I get `arr[1] = value1`; `arr[2] = value2`, etc.
Ideally I need it to be an associative array like: `arr['param1'] = value1` but I am not sure if this is possible in Bash.

Solutions in other languages (PHP, Perl, Python) are acceptable as long as the behaviour of the script remains the same (i.e. it needs to take the query string and output the header + output from the stdout, and be able to kill the process it spawned when the client disconnects).

Any suggestions how to sanitize this input are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the line:

```
arr=(${QUERY_STRING//=/ })
```

With:

```
arr=(${QUERY_STRING//[=&]/ })
```

Then you can get your values in the odd indexes.

#### Example

```
$ QUERY_STRING='param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3'
$ arr=(${QUERY_STRING//[=&]/ })
$ echo ${arr[1]}
value1
$ echo ${arr[3]}
value2
$ echo ${arr[5]}
value3
```

---

Reading your question again, I see you want the values in subsequent indices. You can do that with the [`extglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) shell option as follows:

```
shopt -s extglob # with this you enable 'extglob'
arr=${QUERY_STRING//?(&)+([^&=])=/ }
```

Explanation:

`?(&)`      -> matches zero or one occurrence of `&`
`+([^&=])=` -> matches 1+ occurrences of string without `&` or `=` followed by a `=`

Comment: Thanks! Any comments on sanitization are welcome (i.e. how to make sure value1, value2, etc. don't include a character that would allow executing random commands).

Comment: thanks! this even works for the whole URL with parameters, if you include `?` inside `[]`, the main URL becomes `arr[0]`, first key `arr[1]` and first value `arr[2]` and so on! Nice!